# Javascript: Unix-like datastructure/messaging library

Tags: javascript, unix

Are you aware of any javascript libraries that provide data storage (both persistent and temp) that is reminiscent or the unix filesystem, and/or messaging publishing and subscription reminiscent of unix pipes?

For example:

```
onEvent(e) {
Data.save({string: e.msg, path: "/some/place/mystring.txt"});
}
Pipe.run({from: e, to: f});
```

To be extra clear, I'm asking about javascript libraries that look similar to the above, without actually using anything outside of the javascript VM (such as writing to the local filesystem or running shell commands).

Comment: are you aware of node.js?

Comment: @muratgu clearly I have to rephrase my question.

Comment: Where is JavaScript running? Is it on the client side? I.e. in a browser. Or, is it running on the server side, e.g. node.js